# ggplot how show data for the last month period

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this piece of code.
My goal is plot data for the last month.
I read on the web that it is possible with `scale_x_date(limits = as.Date`
So 1st step I tried plot data in specified timeframe... e.g. 2020-05-01","2020-09-09
but when I insert this code to my ggplot I got this error
`Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`
Any idea what is wrong ?

Dataframe example: read from csv

```
"date","diff"
2020-01-22,555
2020-01-23,99
2020-01-24,287
2020-01-25,493
...
```

Code:

```
##before plot I had to  convert date from posix time, to show properly date in plot
conf_all_data$date <- as.POSIXct(conf_all_data$date)

##ggplot
      
  ggplot(conf_all_data, aes(x=date, y=diff, text=paste(date, "\n" ,  "Confirmed:", diff ))) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity',fill='blue')  +
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2020-05-01","2020-09-09"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma),
  tooltip = "text"
```

One comment added here:
If date is not date as it  looks like, why then ggplot has no problem with correct plotting this chart also with  X date Axis ?
You can check my working site here http://webcovid19.online/, code is in all charts the same, only I removed problematic part with `scale_x_date`,
I have added also screenshot
[image]

Thanks to all, issue was really wrong Date type, when I did debug  in console, I realized that  after read csv to DF is factor type, then I have to convert with As.date()

Anyway my question is if I want show plot of last month period dataframe, e.g. today we have 2020-12-08, Is there some Date function with arithmetic operations to get minus 30 days ( or another number) from today to deal with months crossing ?

Here is my working screenshot with specified working timeframe

```
  ggplot(slovakia_conf_inc, aes(x=date, y=confirmed, text=paste( date,  "\n",  "confirmed:", confirmed ))) + 
        geom_bar(stat='identity',fill='blue')  +
        scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month") +
        scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2020-08-01","2020-09-09"))) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = comma),
      tooltip = "text"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using your data, first try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Transform
conf_all_data$date <- as.Date(conf_all$date)
#Code
ggplot(conf_all_data, aes(x=date, y=diff,
                          label=paste(date, "\n" ,  "Confirmed:", diff ))) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity',fill='blue')  +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Andrew Great! Always a pleasure helping :)

Comment: Hey Duck, it's working because I removed my problematic piece of code : scale_x_date... :)
any idea how to fix ?

Comment: @Andrew Play around `date_breaks` in `scale_x_date()` like `scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month')`

Comment: ` scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month') ` has the same error, anyway I updated my question and screenshot.

Comment: @Andrew Hi. More data is necessary to reproduce your issue. Try uploading to github or using `dput(yourdata)` and paste with the question!

Answer (score 0):

Because your `date`'s are **not** type of `Date`.

Take for example this code with the `economics` dataset and your limit dates:

```
ggplot(data = economics) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = unemploy), 
            color = "#09557f",
            alpha = 0.6,
            size = 0.6) +
  labs(x = "Date", 
       y = "US Unemployed in Thousands",
       title = "Base Plot") +
   scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("1999-05-01","1999-09-09"))) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

The error you are getting is similar to trying to plot `geom_line(aes(x = as.character(date), y = unemploy)`. Which throws an
[image]

Use the [`as.Date`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.Date) function to fix it.

Comment: Hmm, your working example looks similar to my, I have also as.Date function there, `scale_x_date(limits = as.Date` so why not working my example ?

Comment: Is the `date` on top also a `Date`? The `as.Date` should not be only in `scale_x_date`. If both are `Date`'s then perhaps the issue somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, but if date is not type of date, why then ggplot can plot this dataframe with no issues ? How can I check if date is Date ?

Comment: You would use [`is.Date`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.9/topics/is.Date) to check that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just found solution for Subtraction Date with lubridate.
e.g.

```
library(lubridate)
date <- As.Date("2009-10-01")


ymd(date) - 5
# [1] "2009-09-26"
```